# new.js.erb not fired up by ajax call in Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Here is the ajax call responding to change of `name` field. The ajax call should eventually fire up `new.js.erb` to fill up a few fields on current page:

```
$(function (){
    $(document).on('change', "[id^='order_order_items_attributes'][id$='_name']", function (){
    $.get(window.location, $('form').serialize(), null);
    return false;
  });
});
```

After upgrading to Rails 4.2 from 3.2, the `new.js.erb` is not executed any more after the `name` change. In debug, the `$(function(){...})` is executed as normal but the `new.js.erb` is not executed. What's missing in our upgrade?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to specify the dataType as 'script' in the $.get call. If it's defaulting to HTML then it won't load the JS file.

```
$.get(window.location, $('form').serialize(), null, 'script');
```